# Как построить промежуточные значения из списка?

Tags: python, list

Как получить список `a` длинной 60, если первое значение равно 15 а последнее 28?

Речь идет о построении списка `a = [ ]`, в котором от 15 до 28 - это значения начала и конца по прямой линии.

Comment: нужен список от 15 до 28 длиной 60 с одинаковой разницей между числами в нем?

Comment: да, тоесть это прямая линия от 15 до 28 - в данном случае под наклоном

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться функцией [linspace](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linspace.html) библиотеки `numpy`, предназначенной специально для этого: https://ideone.com/td6KKW

```
import numpy as np

a = list(np.linspace(15, 28, 60))
```

Если и дальше планируете работать с объектами `numpy` (что рекомендуется для массивов, матриц и т.д.), то приведение к `list` не нужно.

Answer (score 3):

https://ideone.com/oP4BzF

```
def line(l, r, n):
  s = (r-l) / (n-1)
  return [l+i*s for i in range(n)]

print(line(15, 28, 60))
```

Answer (score 2):

Самое простое - воспользоваться [линейной интерполяцией](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.interpolate.html):

```
In [67]: import pandas as pd

In [68]: a = np.full(60, np.nan, dtype="float")

In [69]: a[0], a[-1] = 15, 28

In [70]: res = pd.Series(a).interpolate()

In [71]: plt.plot(res.index, res, 'o')
Out[71]: [<matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x7f8801bf2550>]
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]